# Why isn't firefox rendering my GIF files better?

Tags: html, css, firefox, rendering, gif

I have some GIF files on my site which are all rendered extremely smooth on every browser excluding FireFox.. the following screens depict what I mean:

**EXAMPLE 1**

Here is rendering of a GIF on basically Safari/Opera/Chrome.. very smooth.

[image]

Here is the rendering on FF.. very choppy and semi distorted lines.

[image]

**EXAMPLE 2**

Rendering on Opera/Safari/Chrome, once again very smooth.

[image]

Rendering on FF, once again very choppy.

[image]

Is this a browser defect that has to be adjusted with settings or? So far I have negated this by adding some browser sniffing logic (which I don't want to do) and placing in a smaller rendition of the GIF. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here are the actual GIF's.. open this question in FF and please provide feed back

[image]
[image]

Comment: good way of explanation

Comment: what version of firefox?

Comment: Why didn't you provided that actual gif?

Comment: as I typed that comment, I literally updated to version 48.0 & have the same issues @vielmetti

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan check update

Comment: Are you talking about the difference in aliasing on the images you linked, or the actual framerate? In either case, I'm flipping back and forth between Firefox (48) and Chrome (52.0.2743.116) and the inline GIFs look identical. (Though, what you were calling 'choppy' above.)

Try hitting CTRL+0 in both browsers to reset your zoom. It's possible one of them is scaling the image, causing filtering to be applied.

Comment: Another thought: are you running a high DPI monitor? If so, Windows?

Comment: I'm using a 13 inch macbook air, approx 128 dpi @TobyDeshane

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my mac mini in FF 48.0.1. The animated GIFs look exactly the same in Chrome (53). Have a look at image-rendering property `https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/` maybe this helps?

Comment: On my retina display and FF 50.1.0 The gif files look exactly the same as on chrome and safari

Comment: Did you try reset the zoom of the browser?  `CMD + 0`, or if you're on Windows `CTRL + 0`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `image-rendering` property? http://caniuse.com/#search=image-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your image is 100%. Sometimes the “halve pixels” can cause troubles on image rendering.

Also, some browsers and some versions tend to display the image differently. At that point, I don't think there's anyting that can be done about that.

Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 0):

The browser may be resizing the image. Resized images lose quality.
Look up lossy images. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility the browser is resizing your image. To avoid this, it's advisable you make the dimensions for your web browser 100% instead of setting width = 1024px. This may not fix all the issues but would at least help fit the GIFs properly into the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108**

[image]

**Firefox Version 71.0 (64-bit)**

[image]

Unable to find any difference on latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is more of a hack than a fix but you can add
in your css

```
.element{
   filter:blur(0.33px);
}
```

I use this on fonts & some images to make them appear smoother, different elements need different amounts of blur but anywhere between 0.24 & 0.54px usually makes fonts and images a lot smoother & removes some level of pixelation.. But I would suggest try the other answers first.